# How to interpret interaction effects in a cox regression?

Tags: survival, interaction, interpretation, cox-model, reporting

[image: variable data]

How would I interpret and report the highlighted boxes?

The variables:
Injury (0=uninjured, 1=injured)
Sex (0=male, 1=female)
Diet(1=10%EA, 2=50%EA, 3=100%EA, 4=150%EA, 5=200%EA)
(note: the “event” is death; the hazard ratio indicates odds of death)